# R predict function using 'prob' type

Tags: r, prediction

I have a data frame ('fulltrans') with sales interaction details. The variable that I am trying to predict upon is if the associate interaction across several variables was effective in resulting in a customer sale ('Flag'). I am attempting to fit a decision tree model to fulltrans with the following code:

```
    '%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')
    trainDataIndex <- createDataPartition(fulltrans$Flag, p=0.7, list=F)
    trainData <- fulltrans[trainDataIndex, ]
    testData <- fulltrans[-trainDataIndex, ]
    down_train <- downSample(x = testData [, colnames(trainData) %ni% "Flag"], y= trainData$Flag)
    rectree_fit <- rpart(Class ~., data = down_train)
    test <- predict(rectree_fit, testData, type = 'prob')
    View(test)
```

After using the model to predict, the output looks like this:

```
                 0         1
    4    0.1623616 0.8376384
    7    0.1623616 0.8376384
    15   0.1623616 0.8376384
    22   0.1147541 0.8852459
    ...
```

If I understand correctly, the left side is the index of specific observations from the data frame. How would I filter for transactions in test where the percentage of 1 is greater than 70% and retrieve the full interaction details associated with those indexes back from the testData?

I have tried this, but there seems to be an issue filtering on a column named 1.

```
     View(filter(test, '1' >= .80))
```

Alternatively, is there a way for me to generate a list of of the index numbers and then only select that list of indexes from the main data frame?

Thanks!

Comment: 1 is a non-standard variable name.  Try putting backticks around it, as in \` 1 \`.

Comment: @DanY thank you for this suggestion. Just tried it and continue to get this error Error in View : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with. I pulled the row names of the test table and indexed those row names from the original data frame, fulltrans.

```
    test <- predict(rectree_fit, testData, type = 'prob')
    index_list <- as.numeric(rownames(test))
    test_w_details <- fulltrans[c(pls),]
    View(test_w_details)
```

The output includes all the original variables and their values for the relevant rows.